# Extending Built-in Array With ES6 Classes - Method is not a function error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to extend built-in array class and create custom collections based native array class.

I'm able to create collection with custom name, it works well, but I can't use my custom methods. If I use findAnimal method it gives me `method is not a function` error. If I log collection and inspect prototypes I can't see my custom methods.

I realized that I transpile down the code into the es5 and if I not, works well, Problem occurs with the ts compiler's es5 downgraded code.

If we use babel to downgrade code into es5, transpiled code works well. Either ts compiler missing something when transpiling the code or I missing some vital configuration.

```
interface Animal {
    name: string;
    weight: number
}

class AnimalCollection extends Array <Animal> {
    constructor(name, ...items) {
        super(...items);

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
            enumerable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: name
        })
    }

    findAnimal(name): Animal {
        return this.find(a => a.name === name) || null;
    }
}

const animalsArray = [
    {name: 'TD-23', weight: 60},
    {name: 'TD-25', weight: 50},
    {name: 'TXD-26', weight: 120},
    {name: 'TYD-26', weight: 40}
];

const animals = new AnimalCollection('Deers', ...animalsArray)

console.log(animals.findAnimal('TD-23'));
// Uncaught TypeError: animals.findAnimal is not a function
```

**ES5 Downgraded**

```js
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var __spreadArrays = (this && this.__spreadArrays) || function () {
    for (var s = 0, i = 0, il = arguments.length; i < il; i++) s += arguments[i].length;
    for (var r = Array(s), k = 0, i = 0; i < il; i++)
        for (var a = arguments[i], j = 0, jl = a.length; j < jl; j++, k++)
            r[k] = a[j];
    return r;
};

var AnimalCollection = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(AnimalCollection, _super);
    function AnimalCollection(name) {
        var items = [];
        for (var _i = 1; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
            items[_i - 1] = arguments[_i];
        }
        var _this = _super.apply(this, items) || this;
        Object.defineProperty(_this, 'name', {
            enumerable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: name
        });
        return _this;
    }
    AnimalCollection.prototype.findAnimal = function (name) {
        return this.find(function (a) { return a.name === name; }) || null;
    };
    return AnimalCollection;
}(Array));
var animalsArray = [
    { name: 'TD-23', weight: 60 },
    { name: 'TD-25', weight: 50 },
    { name: 'TXD-26', weight: 120 },
    { name: 'TYD-26', weight: 40 }
];
var animals = new (AnimalCollection.bind.apply(AnimalCollection, __spreadArrays([void 0, 'Deers'], animalsArray)))();
console.log(animals.findAnimal('TD-23'));
```

Comment: is this typescript or what?

Comment: @Berto99 yeah it is

Comment: The code works fine in the browser https://jsfiddle.net/74kt0wj5/ In what environment does it not work?

Comment: @SwashataGhosh I just discover the if I transpile down to es2015 works fine, but in es5 throws errors.

Comment: Yes it is working fine for me as well

Comment: What it looks like after you converting to es5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATED ANSWER

To answer your modified question, TypeScript doesn't let you extend built-ins like `Array`, `Error` etc. The reason is [written here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work).

> In ES2015, constructors which return an object implicitly substitute
> the value of this for any callers of super(...). It is necessary for
> generated constructor code to capture any potential return value of
> super(...) and replace it with this.
>
> As a result, subclassing Error, Array, and others may no longer work
> as expected. This is due to the fact that constructor functions for
> Error, Array, and the like use ECMAScript 6's new.target to adjust the
> prototype chain; however, there is no way to ensure a value for
> new.target when invoking a constructor in ECMAScript 5. Other
> downlevel compilers generally have the same limitation by default.

So if you must extend built-in `Array` under ES5 environment, then you can try Babel for compiling your code. However be aware that it has it's limitation as [stated here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/caveats/#classes).

> Built-in classes such as Date, Array, DOM etc cannot be properly
> subclassed due to limitations in ES5 (for the transform-classes
> plugin). You can try to use babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend
> based on Object.setPrototypeOf and Reflect.construct, but it also has
> some limitations.

### OLD ANSWER

While the code itself is perfectly find and also executes fine in the browser, I think the error you are getting is because of the TypeScript compiler.

For the source code

```
interface Animal {
    name: string;
    weight: number
}

class AnimalCollection extends Array <Animal> {
    constructor(name: string, ...items: Animal[]) {
        super(...items);

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
            enumerable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: name
        })
    }

    findAnimal(name:string): Animal | null {
        return this.find(a => a.name === name) || null;
    }
}

const animalsArray = [
    {name: 'TD-23', weight: 60},
    {name: 'TD-25', weight: 50},
    {name: 'TXD-26', weight: 120},
    {name: 'TYD-26', weight: 40}
];

const animals = new AnimalCollection('Deers', ...animalsArray)

console.log(animals.findAnimal('TD-23'));
```

If the compiler target option is set to `ES5`, then [it produces code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHMBuY0gdwmCYAswaIAK6YARtEIBfQoQQ44tWmgzYcAYQD2OHBARhgGkMggAPSCAAmS1FChwAnsgA86LLgB8BdiQSH6UIT0NKAAKckoaf2YAGmQAOgTgSExaGldVAG0AXQBKL1ICuiEAB2gQhLikiBSctm9CgHlRACtdMDiLCBhQCAAFKA1SqDB7ELBeYFpYgHJwiGnYokLl42FKO1EdGngcWgho%20pXkDkYwOE3qZB29g6OCgDdcIUu5w9JJHPrpeu7LdNwwhRqFEQEwcmkVLhkAAfMhCbT5FZQCBgIRQIzjSZxX4WEJwZAAXk8cDic0JBIJZCBeWhsOE2jYBWk318IHoyDgkN2NjsjkpGXq%20DmNGmABUACIAWgATABmBbHbh8ATIABsAAZJLdSEKgSKJTKAKwKrg8fg0Q2a7UkXURZBigAaUulqpNSvNyAAjNKrYLhfbRQBNZ2u2Km5U0AAsmsIWTqrPZnLcu0JZAgHGUyc02jaBhAIWm4og0FoCoqSdUtB5Dk%20sj8WggcRwGiYeK5tGxoAs-xwBYNcumOVqQA) that breaks the implementation. The code it generates is

```js
"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var __spreadArrays = (this && this.__spreadArrays) || function () {
    for (var s = 0, i = 0, il = arguments.length; i < il; i++) s += arguments[i].length;
    for (var r = Array(s), k = 0, i = 0; i < il; i++)
        for (var a = arguments[i], j = 0, jl = a.length; j < jl; j++, k++)
            r[k] = a[j];
    return r;
};
var AnimalCollection = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(AnimalCollection, _super);
    function AnimalCollection(name) {
        var items = [];
        for (var _i = 1; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
            items[_i - 1] = arguments[_i];
        }
        var _this = _super.apply(this, items) || this;
        Object.defineProperty(_this, 'name', {
            enumerable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: name
        });
        return _this;
    }
    AnimalCollection.prototype.findAnimal = function (name) {
        return this.find(function (a) { return a.name === name; }) || null;
    };
    return AnimalCollection;
}(Array));
var animalsArray = [
    { name: 'TD-23', weight: 60 },
    { name: 'TD-25', weight: 50 },
    { name: 'TXD-26', weight: 120 },
    { name: 'TYD-26', weight: 40 }
];
var animals = new (AnimalCollection.bind.apply(AnimalCollection, __spreadArrays([void 0, 'Deers'], animalsArray)))();
console.log(animals.findAnimal('TD-23'));
```

However, if we set the `target` in `tsconfig.json` to something equal to or greater than `ES2015`, then the [code it generates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHMBuY0gdwmCYAswaIAK6YARtEIBfQoQQ44tWmgzYcAYQD2OHBARhgGkMggAPSCAAmS1FChwAnsgA86LLgB8BdiQSH6UIT0NKAAKckoaf2YAGmQAOgTgSExaGldVAG0AXQBKL1ICuiEAB2gQhLikiBSctm9CgHlRACtdMDiLCBhQCAAFKA1SqDB7ELBeYFpYgHJwiGnYokLl42FKO1EdGngcWgho%20pXkDkYwOE3qZB29g6OCgDdcIUu5w9JJHPrpeu7LdNwwhRqFEQEwcmkVLhkAAfMhCbT5FZQCBgIRQIzjSZxX4WEJwZAAXk8cDic0JBIJZCBeWhsOE2jYBWk318IHoyDgkN2NjsjkpGXq%20DmNGmABUACIAWgATABmBbHbh8ATIABsAAZJLdSEKgSKJTKAKwKrg8fg0Q2a7UkXURZBigAaUulqpNSvNyAAjNKrYLhfbRQBNZ2u2Km5U0AAsmsIWTqrPZnLcu0JZAgHGUyc02jaBhAIWm4og0FoCoqSdUtB5Dk%20sj8WggcRwGiYeK5tGxoAs-xwBYNcumOVqQA) is

```js
"use strict";
class AnimalCollection extends Array {
    constructor(name, ...items) {
        super(...items);
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
            enumerable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: name
        });
    }
    findAnimal(name) {
        return this.find(a => a.name === name) || null;
    }
}
const animalsArray = [
    { name: 'TD-23', weight: 60 },
    { name: 'TD-25', weight: 50 },
    { name: 'TXD-26', weight: 120 },
    { name: 'TYD-26', weight: 40 }
];
const animals = new AnimalCollection('Deers', ...animalsArray);
console.log(animals.findAnimal('TD-23'));
```

Which of course works. So I think there is an issue in TypeScript compiler for version ES5 or less, which breaks the implementation. I have tried using [Babel for compilation](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=ie%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHMBuY0gdwmCYAswaIAK6YARtEIBfQoQQ44tWmgzYcAYQD2OHBARhgGkMggAPSCAAmS1FChwAnsgA86LLgB8BdiQSH6UIT0NKAAKckoaf2YAGmQAOgTgSExaGldVAG0AXQBKL1ICuiEAB2gQhLikiBSctm9CgHlRACtdMDiLCBhQCAAFKA1SqDB7ELBeYFpYgHJwiGnYokLl42FKO1EdGngcWgho-pXkDkYwOE3qZB29g6OCgDdcIUu5w9JJHPrpeu7LdNwwhRqFEQEwcmkVLhkAAfMhCbT5FZQCBgIRQIzjSZxX4WEJwZAAXk8cDic0JBIJZCBeWhsOE2jYBWk318IHoyDgkN2NjsjkpGXq-DmNGmABUACIAWgATABmBbHbh8ATIABsAAZJLdSEKgSKJTKAKwKrg8fg0Q2a7UkXURZBigAaUulqpNSvNyAAjNKrYLhfbRQBNZ2u2Km5U0AAsmsIWTqrPZnLcu0JZAgHGUyc02jaBhAIWm4og0FoCoqSdUtB5Dk-sj8WggcRwGiYeK5tGxoAs_xwBYNcumOVqQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Ctypescript%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.10.5&externalPlugins=) and it works for ES5.

Comment: it seems something wrong with typescript compiler. but not sure if I missing some configurations. I'm quite beginner to ts

Comment: @TeomanTıngır I got what you are asking and have changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you was missing some `any`, this is the code that works for me:

```
interface Animal {
    name: string;
    weight: number
}

class AnimalCollection extends Array <Animal> {
    constructor(name: string, ...items : Array <Animal>) { // <-- missing types
        super(...items);

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
            enumerable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: name
        })
    }

    findAnimal(name : any): Animal|null { // <-- missing null
        return this.find(a => a.name === name) || null;
    }
}

const animalsArray = [
    {name: 'TD-23', weight: 60},
    {name: 'TD-25', weight: 50},
    {name: 'TXD-26', weight: 120},
    {name: 'TYD-26', weight: 40}
];

const animals = new AnimalCollection('Deers', ...animalsArray)

console.log(animals.findAnimal('TD-23'));
```

However this code generates the following JS:

```
"use strict";
class AnimalCollection extends Array {
    constructor(name, ...items) {
        super(...items);
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
            enumerable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: name
        });
    }
    findAnimal(name) {
        return this.find(a => a.name === name) || null;
    }
}
const animalsArray = [
    { name: 'TD-23', weight: 60 },
    { name: 'TD-25', weight: 50 },
    { name: 'TXD-26', weight: 120 },
    { name: 'TYD-26', weight: 40 }
];
const animals = new AnimalCollection('Deers', ...animalsArray);
console.log(animals.findAnimal('TD-23'));
```

Which does not generate any error

Comment: Why `any`? `name` should be a string, and `items` should be an array of `Animal`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe since the author of the question has not specified the type, i don't know if it may need to accept other types and then extract some values, so i've used `any`,

Comment: but that will be of course string. As I can see the code

Comment: @Berto99, hi thank you for your answer, I just made some adjustment on the question. Problem causing because of es5 transpiling. es2015 works as well. But how I make it work when it downgrade to es5 ?

Answer (score 0):

it's how you wrote your function that causes the error

```js
interface Animal {
    name: string;
    weight: number
}

class AnimalCollection extends Array <Animal> {
    constructor(name, ...items) {
        super(...items);

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
            enumerable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: name
        })
    }

    findAnimal:Animal=(name:String)=> {
        return this.find(a => a.name === name) || null;
    }
}

const animalsArray = [
    {name: 'TD-23', weight: 60},
    {name: 'TD-25', weight: 50},
    {name: 'TXD-26', weight: 120},
    {name: 'TYD-26', weight: 40}
];

const animals = new AnimalCollection('Deers', ...animalsArray)

console.log(animals.findAnimal('TD-23'));
// Uncaught TypeError: animals.findAnimal is not a function
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery ?

Comment: not intentional,  is not javascript it's typescript so I pressed the wrong option by mistake, fixed now

Comment: Okay I have removed that please review and approve